# Did uninstalling Docker from Windows also remove containers and volumes?

Tags: windows, docker, containers, uninstallation, volume

After upgrading Docker from 4.5.1 to 4.7.0 in Windows 10, Docker won't start again. Try to uninstall and install back to an older version, but there is no containers and volumes anymore. Did uninstalling Docker delete my old containers and volumes ? How to get my containers and volumes back ?